# install package via yum found on apt-cache but not yum search

Tags: package-management

I have this library on machine X that manages packages via apt:

`libmemcached-dev - Development files for libmemcached`

And I want it on machine Y that uses yum.  `yum search libmemcached-dev` fails.  What's the safest way to go through with this installation?

X is ubuntu Y is cent-os.

Comment: Add some more detail if you want an answer, what OS' are machines X and Y?

Comment: X is ubuntu, Y is cent-os.

Comment: Try asking the question at superuser.com (another stackexchange site) since it isn't specific here.

Answer (score 0):

In centOs (yum repositories) the developer packages finish with -devel , so

```
    yum install libmemcached-devel
```

is more close to

```
   apt-get install libmemcached-dev
```

Comment: Problem is that winds up being a different library, e.g. uses a .hh instead of a .hpp so I'd have to totally rewrite my code.

Comment: so this question is of another stackexchange site, and maybe you can try with alien